# What sort of theoretical machine would be needed to solve the tiling problem?

Tags: computability

So theoretically, what sort of machine would we need to solve the *tiling problem?*

(Given a set of tiles, decide if they will tile the plane or not.)

I know we could have a Turing machine plus a "tiling oracle", but do we know what, specifically a Turing machine *isn't* able to do that keeps us from being able to compute the answer?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile), the halting problem reduces to the tiling problem. This means that one thing that prevents Turing machines from solving the tiling problem is their inability of deciding whether a given procedure ever halts. The tiling problem might be even more difficult that the halting problem, but unfortunately I wasn't able to confirm or disprove this.